# JavaScript for regex to check for not contains with the starting with the string pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the matching pattern in my phone no for not starting with some string.

For example:

1. Input: +551234467
   Pattern: Not start with +55
2. Input: 557875756
   Pattern: Not start with 55

So far I have tried many patterns and some gives result for only the strings without +.

`/[^(\+55)]/`

`/^(?!\+55).*$/`

`/[?!\+5|55]{2}/`

`/[^\+55|^\+5|^55]/`

What can I try next?

Comment: Check [`^\+?(?!55)\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/gR9yA7/1)

Comment: Your second regex works good: _https://regex101.com/r/gR9yA7/2_

Comment: @Tushar thank you..and I forget to mention one more use case as 557875756 also should not match. Means +55 & 55

Comment: @Prabhakaran Please update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I forget to mention one more use case as 557875756 also should not match. Means +55 & 55 - by OP in comment to the question

Use following regex.

```
^\+?(?!55)\d+$
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/gR9yA7/1)

1. `^`: Starts with Anchor
2. `\+?`: Matches zero or one `+` symbol
3. `(?!55)`: Negative look-ahead, does not match 55
4. `\d+`: Matches one or more digits
5. `$`: Ends with Anchor

**Demo**

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\+?(?!55)\d+" />
```

Comment: Good to see the full demo version +1

Comment: @RahulTripathi Thank you.